# editable kendo ui from html table and dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i want use html table for data source of kendo-ui jquery.and also edit inline with drop-down list. for this purpose, i wrote below code

My problem is when user double click on the row of table and edit status table, instead of StatusName in the grid, StatusID is recorded.

HTML:

```
 <table id="grid">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Tag Number</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                 <tr><td>P-502</td><td>Running</td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>P-504</td><td>Running</td></tr>
                             </tbody>
                             </table>
```

JS Code:

```
 $('#grid').kendoGrid({

                pageable: true,
                editable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 8
                },
                columns: [
                    {field:"tagNumber", title:"Tag Number", editable:false},
                    {field:"status", title:"Status", editor: statusDropDownEditor}
                ]
            });
            function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "StatusName",
                        dataValueField: "StatusID",
                        index:0,
                        dataSource: [
                            {StatusID:1, StatusName:"Running"},
                            {StatusID:2, StatusName:"Stop"},
                            {StatusID:3, StatusName:"N/A"}
                        ]
                    });
            }

        });
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please take the time to read the answer and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the values property of the column options to specify the list of foreign key values for that field.

using the example:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn

here is a dojo to show you how it works in your case
https://dojo.telerik.com/esicuwIw

and the code:

```
<script>

    let statuses = [
        {StatusID:1, StatusName:"Running"},
        {StatusID:2, StatusName:"Stop"},
        {StatusID:3, StatusName:"N/A"}
   ];

  let statusForColumnOptions = statuses.map(function(s) {
        return {
        value: s.StatusID,
        text: s.StatusName
      };
  });

  function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "StatusName",
      dataValueField: "StatusID",
      index:0,
      dataSource: statuses
    });
  }

  $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    pageable: true,
    editable: true,
    dataSource: {
      pageSize: 8,
      data: [
        { tagNumber: 'P-502', status: 1 },
        { tagNumber: 'P-504', status: 1 }
      ]
    },
    columns: [
      {field:"tagNumber", title:"Tag Number", editable:false},
      {field:"status", title:"Status", values: statusForColumnOptions, editor: statusDropDownEditor}
    ]
  });
```